# Connecting four ADXL345 sensors to Arduino UNO using TCA9548A multiplexer

Tags: arduino, arduino-uno

I am able to run two ADXL345 sensor using the address, 0x1D and 0x53. However, after adding the TCA9548A multiplexer using another two address: 0x4A and 0x4B. I am not able to receive data from the two addresses added. I need to run all four ADXL345 sensors using one Arduino UNO and therefore used the multiplexer to provide me with my addresses to fit all.

This is the code that I have tried and I can't seem to get the data values from the sensors addressed as 0x4A and 0x4B.

```
#include <Wire.h>

int ADXL345Lstart = 0x53;
int ADXL345Rstart = 0x1D;
int ADXL345Lend = 0x4A;
int ADXL345Rend = 0x4B;
int TCA9548A = 0x70;
float Xls_out, Yls_out, Zls_out, Xrs_out, Yrs_out, Zrs_out, Xle_out, Yle_out, Zle_out, Xre_out, Yre_out, Zre_out;

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  Wire.begin();

{
  Wire.beginTransmission(TCA9548A);
  Wire.write(0x02); // Channel 2 for L Start
  Wire.endTransmission();

  // Initialize ADXL345start
  Wire.beginTransmission(ADXL345Lstart);
  Wire.write(0x2D);
  Wire.write(8);
  Wire.endTransmission();
  delay(10);
}

{
  Wire.beginTransmission(TCA9548A);
  Wire.write(0x03); // Channel 3 for R Start
  Wire.endTransmission();

  Wire.beginTransmission(ADXL345Rstart);
  Wire.write(0x2D);
  Wire.write(8);
  Wire.endTransmission();
  delay(10);
}

{
  Wire.beginTransmission(TCA9548A);
  Wire.write(0x04); // Channel 4 for L End
  Wire.endTransmission();

  // Initialize ADXL345end
  Wire.beginTransmission(ADXL345Lend);
  Wire.write(0x2D);
  Wire.write(8);
  Wire.endTransmission();
  delay(10);
}

  Wire.beginTransmission(TCA9548A);
  Wire.write(0x05); // Channel 5 for R End
  Wire.endTransmission();

  Wire.beginTransmission(ADXL345Rend);
  Wire.write(0x2D);
  Wire.write(8);
  Wire.endTransmission();
   delay(10);

  // Send channel labels once at the beginning
  Serial.println("CH1,CH2,CH3,CH4,CH5,CH6,CH7,CH8,CH9,CH10,CH11,CH12");
}

void loop(void) {

  Wire.beginTransmission(TCA9548A);
  Wire.write(0x02); //select channel 2
  Wire.endTransmission();

  Wire.beginTransmission(ADXL345Lstart);
  Wire.write(0x32);
  Wire.endTransmission(false);
  Wire.requestFrom(ADXL345Lstart, 6, true);
  Xls_out = (Wire.read() | Wire.read() << 8);
  Xls_out = Xls_out / 256;
  Yls_out = (Wire.read() | Wire.read() << 8);
  Yls_out = Yls_out / 256;
  Zls_out = (Wire.read() | Wire.read() << 8);
  Zls_out = Zls_out / 256;

  Serial.print(Xls_out, 4);
  Serial.print(",");
  Serial.print(Yls_out, 4);
  Serial.print(",");
  Serial.print(Zls_out, 4);

  Wire.beginTransmission(TCA9548A);
  Wire.write(0x03); // Select channel 3
  Wire.endTransmission();

  Wire.beginTransmission(ADXL345Rstart);
  Wire.write(0x32);
  Wire.endTransmission(false);
  Wire.requestFrom(ADXL345Rstart, 6, true);
  Xrs_out = (Wire.read() | Wire.read() << 8);
  Xrs_out = Xrs_out / 256;
  Yrs_out = (Wire.read() | Wire.read() << 8);
  Yrs_out = Yrs_out / 256;
  Zrs_out = (Wire.read() | Wire.read() << 8);
  Zrs_out = Zrs_out / 256;

  Serial.print (",");
  Serial.print(Xrs_out, 4);
  Serial.print(",");
  Serial.print(Yrs_out, 4);
  Serial.print(",");
  Serial.print(Zrs_out, 4);

  Wire.beginTransmission(TCA9548A);
  Wire.write(0x04); // Select channel 4
  Wire.endTransmission();
 
  Wire.beginTransmission(ADXL345Lend);
  Wire.write(0x32);
  Wire.endTransmission(false);
  Wire.requestFrom(ADXL345Lend, 6, true);
  Xle_out = (Wire.read() | Wire.read() << 8);
  Xle_out = Xle_out / 256;
  Yle_out = (Wire.read() | Wire.read() << 8);
  Yle_out = Yle_out / 256;
  Zle_out = (Wire.read() | Wire.read() << 8);
  Zle_out = Zle_out / 256;

  Serial.print(",");
  Serial.print(Xle_out, 4);
  Serial.print(",");
  Serial.print(Yle_out, 4);
  Serial.print(",");
  Serial.print(Zle_out, 4);

  Wire.beginTransmission(TCA9548A);
  Wire.write(0x05); // Select channel 5
  Wire.endTransmission();

  Wire.beginTransmission(ADXL345Rend);
  Wire.write(0x32);
  Wire.endTransmission(false);
  Wire.requestFrom(ADXL345Rend, 6, true);
  Xre_out = (Wire.read() | Wire.read() << 8);
  Xre_out = Xre_out / 256;
  Yre_out = (Wire.read() | Wire.read() << 8);
  Yre_out = Yre_out / 256;
  Zre_out = (Wire.read() | Wire.read() << 8);
  Zre_out = Zre_out / 256;

  Serial.print(",");
  Serial.print(Xre_out, 4);
  Serial.print(",");
  Serial.print(Yre_out, 4);
  Serial.print(",");
  Serial.print(Zre_out, 4);
  Serial.println();
}
```

Comment: An ADXL345 chip can only has I2c address of either 0x1D or 0x53, it won’t be able to change to 0x4A or 0x4B just because you are using a multiplexer

Comment: How can I make this work with the use of TCA9548A multiplexer? Declare all under one address? Since I'm using the multiplexer

Comment: Read the datasheet of TCA9548A. It basically you write to TCA9548A control register to tell which channel you want to use, and then you communicate with the devices on that channel like the normal way you communicate with the i2c slave devices, and when you are done, you write the TCA9548A again to disable the channel or switch to another channel. You can have two ADXL345 on each channel, one on 0x1d address and another on 0x53 address.

Answer (score 1):

> Please noted that the code is written based on the understanding from the [TCA9548A datasheet](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/tca9548a.pdf), it has not been tested on an actual chip yet. The code for the ADXL345 came directly from OP's code with minor coding style changes.

An ADXL345 chip can only has I2C address of either 0x1D or 0x53, it won’t be able to change to 0x4A or 0x4B just because you are using a multiplexer. The fact that ADXL345 can only has one of the two I2C addresses means that on a I2C bus, you could only have two ADXL345 chips on the same bus, in order to solve this problem, The multiplexer such as TCA9548A can be used to allows the I2C devices that have the same I2c addresses to be operated on different channel (i.e. different I2C bus) by time-multiplexing the selected channel.

To use the TCA9548A, you can connect up to two ADXL345s to each channel as shown in the diagram.

[image: TCA9548A]

The following code illustrates the usage of the TCA9548A with the assumptions that you had two ADXL345s on channel 0 and channel 1 with I2C address of 0x1D and 0x53 on each channel.

```cpp
#include <Wire.h>

int ADXL345_CH0_ONE = 0x53;
int ADXL345_CH0_TWO = 0x1D;
int ADXL345_CH1_ONE = 0x53;
int ADXL345_CH1_TWO = 0x1D;
int TCA9548A = 0x70;

void set_mux_channel(int ch) {
  Wire.beginTransmission(TCA9548A);
  Wire.write(1 << ch);
  Wire.endTransmission();
}

void reset_mux_channel(int ch) {
  Wire.beginTransmission(TCA9548A);
  Wire.write((0 & ~(1 << ch)));
  Wire.endTransmission();
}

void read_ADXL_from(int i2c_dev) {
  Wire.beginTransmission(i2c_dev);
  Wire.write(0x32);
  Wire.endTransmission(false);

  Wire.requestFrom(i2c_dev, 6, true);
  //wait until 6 bytes are available
  while (Wire.available() != 6) {
    delay(1);
  }; 

  float Xls_out = (Wire.read() | Wire.read() << 8) / 256.0;
  float Yls_out = (Wire.read() | Wire.read() << 8) / 256.0;
  flat Zls_out = (Wire.read() | Wire.read() << 8) / 256.0;

  Serial.print(Xls_out, 4);
  Serial.print(",");
  Serial.print(Yls_out, 4);
  Serial.print(",");
  Serial.println(Zls_out, 4);
}

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  Wire.begin();
}

void loop(void) {

  set_mux_channel(0);
  read_ADXL_from(ADXL345_CH0_ONE);
  read_ADXL_from(ADXL345_CH0_TWO);
  reset_mux_channel(0);

  select_mux_channel(1);
  read_ADXL_from(ADXL345_CH1_ONE);
  read_ADXL_from(ADXL345_CH1_TWO);
  reset_mux_channel(1);

  delay(1000);
}
```

Comment: As I said, I didn't test the code, and I didn't change your ADXL code.  I won't post this as an answer if it is not requested by you (because I can't test it). If you are new and don't know to debug, I would suggest you use a library such as [this one](https://www.arduino.cc/reference/en/libraries/tca9548a/).